# Will resetting the Google reCAPTCHA force me to fill a CAPTCHA?

Tags: javascript, angular, bots, recaptcha

I'm using the new invisible Google reCAPTCHA and in order to make it work, i need to explicitly execute it by calling the .execute() function.

However, sometimes I need to reset the CAPTCHA using the .reset() function.

If I'm a trusted user and the CAPTCHA doesn't show for me the first time, will it show after I call the .reset() function?

The scenario is as follows:
-Enter the site
-Fill a form
-Click submit
-No CAPTCHA shown

If I reset the CAPTCHA and then repeat the scenario, should I see a CAPTCHA or it should pass again without me filling some images?